# IList's not being Posted Back in viewmodel

Tags: list, model-view-controller, razor, postback, viewmodel

I have a MVC page that is doing some weird things.  I have a class that contains two ILists, Branches and Users.

```html
public class ThirdPartyViewModel
{
    public String MessageText { get; set; }
    public BranchAddress Address { get; set; }
    public String AddressBranchCode { get; set; }
    public String FullAddressBlock { get; set; }

    public IList<ThirdPartySubUserLine> ThirdPartyUsers { get; set; }
    public IList<ThirdPartyBranch> ThirdPartyBranches { get; set; }
    public String BrandStyle { get; set; }
}
```

The view contains 2x tabs and 2x EditorFor with templates

```html
<div id="tabContainer" class="container">  
    <ul class="tabs">  
     <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab1">Users</li>
     <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab2">Branches</li>
    </ul>  
  
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-content current">  
     <table>
        <tbody id="mainList" style="display: block; overflow: auto;">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ThirdPartyUsers, new { editor = "users" })           
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">
     <table>
        <tbody id="mainListSec"  style="display: block; overflow: auto;">
            @Html.EditorFor(t => t.ThirdPartyBranches, new { editor = "data" })
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
        <input id="btnSave" name="Save" type="submit" title="SAVE" />
</div>
```

The 2x Templates look like this:

```html
@model MVC.Controllers.ThirdPartyController.ThirdPartyBranch

<tr style="vertical-align: top;" lineType="@(ViewData["editor"])">
 <td style="width: 200px; text-align: left; font-size: x-small;">
        @Html.HiddenFor(t => t.Changed, new { @class = ViewData["editor"] + "RowChanged", value="false" })

        @(Model.BranchText)

        @Html.HiddenFor(t => t.BranchText, new { @class="br_name" })
    </td>
 <td style="width: 120px; text-align: left; font-size: x-small;">
        @Html.DisplayFor(t => t.BranchTown)
        @Html.HiddenFor(t => t.BranchTown, new { @class="br_town" })
    </td>
 <td style="width: 80px; text-align: center; font-size: x-small;">
        @Html.DisplayFor(t => t.BranchPostalCode)
        @Html.HiddenFor(t => t.BranchPostalCode, new { @class="br_postcode" })
    </td>
 <td style="width: 80px; text-align: center; font-size: x-small;">
        @Html.DisplayFor(t => t.Branch)
        @Html.HiddenFor(t => t.Branch, new { @class="br_code" })
    </td>
    <td style="width: 90px; text-align: center;">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(t => t.isFlaggedAsRetailer, new { @class = "incLabour" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

2nd Template

```html
@model MVC.Controllers.ThirdPartyController.ThirdPartySubUserLine

<tr style="vertical-align: top;" lineType="@(ViewData["editor2"])">
 <td style="width: 200px; text-align: left; font-size: x-small;">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Changed, new { @class = ViewData["editor2"] + "RowChanged2", value="false" })
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UserID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserID, new { @class="br_userid" })
    </td>
 <td style="width: 120px; text-align: left; font-size: x-small;">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UserFirstName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserFirstName, new { @class="br_userfname" })
    </td>
 <td style="width: 80px; text-align: center; font-size: x-small;">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UserLastName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserLastName, new { @class="br_userlname" })
    </td>
 <td style="width: 90px; text-align: center;">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isFlaggedAsRetailer, new { @class = "allowRetailer" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

The issue I have is in the controller.  I'm not getting the viewmodel posted back all the time.

```html
[HttpPost]
[Button(ButtonName = "Save")]
[ActionName("List")]
public ActionResult Save(ThirdPartyViewModel postedViewModel)
{
     //somecode
}
```

In the controller, under the 'Save' ActionResult, I'm not always getting both IList back. This is what I do know:

1. Changing the Database doesn’t make a difference
2. Saving Users always works
3. Saving Branches only works when the number of Users is the
   same or less than the number of Branches
4. Removing the ‘editorfor’ for Users allows Branches to be Saved, even when more users exists
5. Having less Users than branches, the users still save
6. Swapping the two ‘editorfor’ around makes no difference
7. Swapping the two iList around in the viewmodel makes no difference
8. I’ve tried to make both editor templates different by adding a number
   “2” in certain places, makes no difference

I hope I have supplied enough info for someone spot the mistake I have made but if not please ask. I hope it's something silly.  I've been looking at this too long.  Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Spent most of yesterday looking at this.  I connected Fiddler and watched what was being posted back.  In all cases the details for both ILists are being posted back but when you hover over the postback viewmodel in vs2013 the branches IList is null under certain conditions.  If you look at the 'Request.Form' you can see the results every time, so I have done a Dirty Hack (see below).  By looking at Fiddler I also noticed that the 'CheckBoxFor' controls were returning either 'False' or 'False, True', so I had process that.

Still raises the question WHY?

```html
if (postedViewModel.ThirdPartyBranches != null)
{
  foreach (ThirdPartyBranch item in postedViewModel.ThirdPartyBranches)
  {
    //Do Update;
  }
}
else
{
  if (Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("ThirdPartyBranch[0].Branch"))
  {
    string LastKey = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(n => n.StartsWith("ThirdPartyBranch[")).Last();
    int LastKeyNumber = int.Parse(LastKey.Split('[', ']')[1]) + 1;

    for (int b = 0; b < LastKeyNumber; b++)
    {
      string updatebranch = Request.Form["ThirdPartyBranch[" + b.ToString() + "].Branch"].ToString();
      string updateisFlaggedAsRetailer = Request.Form["ThirdPartyBranch[" + b.ToString() + "].isBranchFlaggedAsRetailer"].ToString();
      if(updateisFlaggedAsRetailer.Contains("true"))
      {
        //Do Update to True;
      }
      else
      {
        //Do Update to False;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me. Something to try may be initialising the two lists in the model's default constructor. I had an issue before where the model binder would not create the lists but would populate them if they were not null.

```
public class ThirdPartyViewModel
{
    public String MessageText { get; set; }
    public BranchAddress Address { get; set; }
    public String AddressBranchCode { get; set; }
    public String FullAddressBlock { get; set; }

    public IList<ThirdPartySubUserLine> ThirdPartyUsers { get; set; }
    public IList<ThirdPartyBranch> ThirdPartyBranches { get; set; }
    public String BrandStyle { get; set; }

    public ThirdPartyViewModel()
    {
        ThirdPartyUsers = new List<ThirdPartySubUserLine>();
        ThirdPartyBranches = new List<ThirdPartyBranch>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I always get the 2x lists populated and showing on screen but I don't always get both lists posted back.  Thanks

Comment: Check that the generated html has the correct property names, eg: ThirdPartyUsers[0].UserId. Another issue I had is when input fields are disabled before submit, they are not included in the post data. But I can't see if you disable any items.

Comment: Just had a look at the 'View Source'.  Sorry no problems.  Everything unique and not disabled

Comment: Did you try putting a default constructor into the model to initialise both lists? It was an issue with the model binder I was having, ie post from view to controller.

Comment: I have added an example to the answer. If this doesn't solve the problem, there may be an issue with the model binder.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas. I even created a new mvc application using the details you posted here and the lists are both successfully posted to and useable in the controller.